# Texture Paint: No brush on UV map (Left)

Tags: texture-painting

[image: My Problem]
I was following Blender Guru's 2.8 tutorial, when he got to texture painting.
It was going well until I tried painting on the UV map like he did.
I am literally missing the Bush tool from the Tool Bar.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Before any ask no the UV Map not the 3D view, I see the 3D view has it. But I need it in the UV map.
[image: Closer View]
Because of confusion of whether I was in Texture Paint here is a closer view.
As I stated in a comment I used the 3D view to paint. Hence the discrepancies.

Comment: I just said screwbit and used the 3D view, slow but works. Still would love too is the UV map.

Comment: Maybe check and see if you are using the UV editor or the Image Editor, as in 2.8 the two are separate editors now.

Comment: If you mean Texture Paint vs UV Editing, it shows I'm using Texture Paint. I'll google it anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I think that the solution is in the headed - I assume that the top is what you have set to 'View' and the bottom is what you need set to 'Paint'
[image]

Comment: Oh you did mean UV Editor. And no, I am in Texture Paint.

Comment: see above, does this look like what you need?

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Comment: It won't let me upvote even though I can comment and have confirmed my account. Sorry.

Comment: Can confirm, can't upvote. I'll come back, thanks again.